# CNN Regression on Grid - Limitation of Convolutional Neural Networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm working on a (high energy physics related) problem using CNNs.

For understanding the problem, let's consider [these examples here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVLJE.jpg)

The left-hand side is the input to the CNN, the right-hand side the desired output. So the network is supposed to cluster the input. The actual algorithm behind this clustering (i.e. how we got the desired output for training) is really complex and we want the CNN to learn this.

I've tried different CNN architectures, for example one similar to the U-net architecture (https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04597) but also various concatenations of convolutional layers, etc.

The outputs are always really similar (for all architectures).
[Here you can see some CNN predictions.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPBms.jpg)

In principle the network is performing quite well, but as you can see, in most cases the CNN output consists of several filled pixels that are directly next to each other, which will never (!) happen in the true cases.

I've been using mean squared error as the loss function in all of the networks.

Do you have any suggestions how one could avoid this problem and improve the networks performance?

Or is this a general limitation to CNNs and in practice it is not possible to solve such a problem using CNNs?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to split up the work. First use a U-Shaped NN to find the activations in a binary segmentation task (like in your paper) and then regress on the found activations to find their final values. In my experience this works way better than doing regression on large images, because the MSE will result in blurry outputs, as you have observed.

Comment: Thank you! But instead of binary segmentation I probably should be using multiple-class segmentation since I can have up to 10 of these different objects/clusters in one image, right? Or did you mean something else?

Answer (score 0):

The CNN does not know that you wanted a sharp result. As mentioned by @Thomas, MSE tends to give you blurry result as it is the nature of that loss function. Giving a blurry result does not introduce large loss in MSE.

An easy modification would be to use L1 Loss (absolute difference instead of squared error). It has a constant gradient unlike MSE whose gradient decreases with error.

If you *really* wanted a sharp result, it would be easier to add a manual step -- non maximum suppression (NMS). In practice, a 3x3 box-max filter might do.